# Broken UI and multiple console errors when deploying Nexus3 on Docker and an nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, nexus

I am running `Nexus3` in `Docker` as well as an `nginx reverse-proxy` on `Docker`. I have my own `ssl` certificate. I followed the instructions from Sonatype on how to properly handle using a reverse proxy and use the Nexus3 certificates. Problem is that this is what I see when I go to my repository:[image]

These are my errors: [image: errors]

What could cause this? This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/confidential.com/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/confidential.com/*.confidential.com.key;
        server_name internal.confidential.com;

    location /test {
      proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }
```

Comment: Is there anything in the log files (nginx and nexus)?

Comment: @Henry This is what I am getting for logs in nexus: 
2019-07-01 03:40:00,016+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-3] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2019-07-01 03:40:00,027+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-3] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)